# How to change the UI layout with code that has used Auto Layout in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have a login view that use Auto Layout. When I click Username textfiled to enter some informations the view will pop up keyboard, then the keyboard will block some UIs. I want change some UI's frame info when pop up keyboard in the code, However due to the UI using Auto Layout, so set UI's frame in the code dose not work.

How should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make an IBOutlet to the constraint you want to modify, and change (animated if you  want) the value of its constant property in code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate a `NSLayoutConstraint`'s constant value.

So you create one like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginBox:UIView?;
    var loginBoxTopConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        ...

        self.initConstraints();

    }

    func initConstraints()
    {
        // init constraints here
    }

    ...

}
```

Then you init that constraint to something like this:

```
func initConstraints()
{

    ...

    self.loginBoxTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.loginBox!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150.0);

    self.view.addConstraint(self.loginBoxTopConstraint!);
}
```

Now when your user taps on one of your login fields, your UITextField delegate didBeginEditing gets called. This is where you animate the constraint constant value:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    ...        

    self.loginBoxTopConstraint?.constant = 20.0; // was 150 before

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded();

    });

}
```

When the user is finished with entering text fields, the textFieldDidEnd delegate method should get called:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    ...

    self.loginBoxTopConstraint?.constant = 150.0; // reset to 150

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded();

    });

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have set the constaints in Storyboard, so in `initConstraints` function should be obtain `loginBox`'s constaints instead of create and add a constaint, right? How do I get loginBox's constaint?

Comment: No, you need to you declare and use the NSLayoutConstraint property like I show above. The constraint you specified in your storyboard are fixed constraints, they're not animatable.

Comment: Constraints made in the storyboard are not fixed, that is wrong. You can modify them just like ones you create in code.

Comment: So,how do I get the constaint that made with storyboard in code?

Comment: Made a constaint IBOutLet in ViewController?